# Spring boot modify content-type header in actuator endpoint response

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-admin

I have a spring boot application that returns content-type as application/json in response headers but in spring-boot admin it requires content-type as application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2 in response header. Due to this the data is not shown on spring-boot admin UI. I have tried many different ways but nothing seems to work. Is there any way I can override this header in my application ?

Comment: Can you please provide the Spring Boot version used in the monitored application and also the Spring Boot and Spring Boot Admin version used in the Spring Boot Admin app? Are you talking about standard actuators or self written? Any other config you changed?

Comment: I was able to fix it using this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54501013/10092112.
Thanks for the help anyways.