# Unsupported media type 415 in spring MVC and cannot change Accept type in header

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am getting an unsupported Media type (status code of 415).

I know why this is happening but am looking for an alternate solution to it.I have seen the answers where you change the header but for this customer that seems to be a difficulty.

The sender is a rest call from another company application.  They don't set the Accept:application/json in the sending header.  I know that this is why the call is failing.

I know that for this to work they should set this header.  However, they are reluctant to do so.

My endpoint is as follows:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/keycontentprovider")
public class KMSKeyContentProviderController {

    @Autowired
    private KeyContentProviderService keyContentProviderService;

    @RequestMapping(
            value = "/generate",
            method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> generateContentKey(@RequestBody final KeyGenerateRequestDTO keyGenerateRequestDTO,
                                                @RequestParam(value = "contentType", required = true) String contentType,
                                                @RequestParam(value = "streamingProtocol", required = true) String streamingProtocol,
                                                @RequestParam(value = "encryptionAlgorithm", required = true) String encryptionAlgorithm) {
        return keyContentProviderService.generateKey(keyGenerateRequestDTO.getRequest(), contentType, streamingProtocol, encryptionAlgorithm);
    }
}
```

I have tried to put various types of consumes="" in the RequestMapping definition but no luck.

The customer really doesn't want to change their code (even though they shoudl).  Anyway that I can get around this?

Comment: You can add a header in request thru filter..check this link, here header is added in response http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16190699/automatically-add-header-to-every-response

Comment: isn't that answer for the response?  I need to handle it for incoming requests

Comment: yes thats for response..i gave this link to you so that you get an idea..see if you can do something similar for request

Comment: ok will take a look

Comment: Sure...The point is to try creating a filter to add a header to request

Comment: Accept has nothing to do with 415.  A bad Accept would result in a 406 (Not Acceptable). 415 deals with Content-Type (Unsupported Media Type)

Comment: @peeskillet you are right

Comment: I meant to write Content-type instead of Accept because I am using content-type.

Comment: however, even after writing an interceptor and seeing it execute, somethign else seems to be responding on the content-type before it gets to my interceptor.