# Spring auto-add 'X-Total-Count' header

Tags: java, spring, rest, http

I'm using 'admin-on-rest' UI for my Web-application and it has next restriction:

> Note: The jsonServer REST client expects the API to include a
>   X-Total-Count header in the response to GET_LIST calls. The value must
>   be the total number of resources in the collection. This allows
>   admin-on-rest to know how many pages of resources there are in total,
>   and build the pagination controls.

I solved the problem by adding X-Total-Count header to my list-returning REST-endpoints manually like this:
`response.addHeader("X-Total-Count", String.valueOf(outputList.size()));`

But I'm wondering: if there's some elegant way to do it automatically in Spring? I mean auto-add this header with proper value when some endpoint returns JSON-list?

Comment: If you are trying to add the header for many requests, you can use a filter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16191770/1646783

Comment: @jlars62, I've been thinking about filters, but what is the proper way to distinguish endpoints which return single item in their JSON-response from endpoints which return multiple items in their JSON-response? I need that header only for last ones.

Comment: @DmytroTitov using the PagingAndSortingRepository spring does most of work for you and the total is real (based on the query) and not just a count of the list returned :) Check my answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, there is! (If you are using spring 4.1 or above).

It's called [ResponseBodyAdvice](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseBodyAdvice.html) and it enables you to intercept calls (just before response is written and gives access to raw http response).

Basically what you need is to implement controller advice like this:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ResourceSizeAdvice implements ResponseBodyAdvice<Collection<?>> {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(MethodParameter returnType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
        //Checks if this advice is applicable. 
        //In this case it applies to any endpoint which returns a collection.
        return Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(returnType.getParameterType()); 
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<?> beforeBodyWrite(Collection<?> body, MethodParameter returnType, MediaType selectedContentType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> selectedConverterType, ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response) {
        response.getHeaders().add("X-Total-Count", String.valueOf(body.size()));
        return body;
    }
}
```

Comment: You won't believe, but I came up with this solutions just seconds ago :) Anyway thank you and I accept the answer.

Comment: P.S. I also discovered `@RestControllerAdvice`, which I guess fits better for the REST API case.

Comment: Yeah, if you're on 4.3+ :)

Comment: check my answer in case you want to have the total number of elements in the repository instead of the request :)

Answer (score 5):

In case you don't want just the total number of the elements in the response but the total number of entities in the corresponding JPA method of `PagingAndSortingRepository` you can do something like that which is useful for paging applications :)

Inspired by Bohdan's answer ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/44376133/986160)

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ResourceSizeAdvice implements ResponseBodyAdvice<Page<?>> {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(MethodParameter returnType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
        //Checks if this advice is applicable.
        //In this case it applies to any endpoint which returns a page.
        return Page.class.isAssignableFrom(returnType.getParameterType());
    }

    @Override
    public Page<?> beforeBodyWrite(Page<?> page, MethodParameter methodParameter, MediaType mediaType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> aClass, ServerHttpRequest serverHttpRequest, ServerHttpResponse serverHttpResponse) {
        serverHttpResponse.getHeaders().add("X-Total-Count",String.valueOf(page.getTotalElements()));
        return page;
    }

}
```

Make sure to call the Pageable version of the default methods like so it returns a `Page` and not a `List`:

```
repository.findAll(new PageRequest(0,100));
```

If you are not using Repositories then you have to do two queries:
`Select * from ...` and
`Select count(*) from ...`
and return a `Wrapper` which has contents for the list of results plus total for the total coming from count. Then you can change the `@ControllerAdvice` class to expect your `Wrapper` and get the total from it and put it in the header

Comment: Yeah, nice combo! :)

Comment: @BohdanLevchenko thanks! Although I realized that it is more difficult to count when you have applied some filtering to the repository.. not sure how to make it work like that yet - if I find a way I will post it :)

Comment: @BohdanLevchenko made it :)

Comment: Neat! Clean and simple!

Comment: Cool solution, thanks. But only for repo-based endpoints. Mine actually were fetching data not from the repo, but from some other service. So the collection-size estimation is probably the most general approach. But still: good solution :)

Comment: :) if that is the case then you need to be doing a second query every-time to get the exact count and put the results in a specific wrapper that contains the contents plus the total.. Then you can change the @ControllerAdvice class to expect your `WrapperClass` and get the total from it and put it in the header

Comment: btw if you return a Page Iterable from a Controller.. it is an object that has content with an array of elements, pagination details and total

Answer (score 1):

Because from Page you can get total elements. So I've added headers to ResponseEntity

```
@GetMapping(value = POSTS, headers = "Accept=application/json")
public ResponseEntity<?> getListPost(@RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "0") Integer page, @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "25") Integer size) {
    // Create pageable
    Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(page, size);
    Page<Post> pagePost = postService.getPagePost(pageable);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders() {
        {
            add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content-Range");
            add("Content-Range", String.valueOf(pagePost.getTotalElements()));
        }
    };
    //        return new ResponseEntity<>(new CommonResponseBody("OK", 200, postList), HttpStatus.OK);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(new CommonResponseBody("OK", 200, new LinkedHashMap() {
        {
            put("data", pagePost.getContent());
        }
    }), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

getPagePost is service method which uses Page findAll(Pageable pageable) in Repository.

**Note:** Change Content-Range to X-Total-Count if it doesn't work for you.