# Spring auto-add 'X-Total-Count' header for selected endpoints

Tags: java, spring, rest, http

I know that I can use ResponseBodyAdvice and that it enables me to intercept calls (just before response is written and gives access to the raw http response). Like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44375435/spring-auto-add-x-total-count-header?newreg=6349a33f06564f2d92d494c805ad2162).
But how I can configure that this should not be done for all endpoints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not into a generic approach then why not just add your custom response header right in your specific controller methods, e.g. like here https://www.techiedelight.com/add-header-to-response-spring-boot/. Other than that you could still use the `ResponseBodyAdvice` approach but would have to programmatically do the filtering, e.g. by comparing the request's path (URL) in your `ResponseBodyAdvice` implementation (in method `beforeBodyWrite` - there you have access to the request to determine the path):

```
T beforeBodyWrite(T body, MethodParameter returnType, MediaType selectedContentType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> selectedConverterType, ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response)
```

Also see examples here: https://mtyurt.net/post/spring-modify-response-headers-after-processing.html