# Override the jHipster JhiAlertErrorComponent http error listener

Tags: angular, typescript, jhipster

We have a front end jHipster application (v.4.8.0) which uses Angular 4. There is an alert-error-component.ts (JhiAlertErrorComponent) which includes an http error listener which intercepts all errors returned in Http responses throughout the application.

See here: https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app-ng2/blob/master/src/main/webapp/app/shared/alert/alert-error.component.ts

This displays a little error box at the top of the window which is perfect in most cases but we now have some cases where we want to perform some custom behaviour on http errors.

Is there an elegant way to override the http error listener in this error component and instead handle the error locally for specific cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by using an HTTP header to distinguish requests where I want any HTTP error responses not to be handled by the JHipster alert error component.

This works by using a filter as described here:
[automatically add header to every response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16190699/automatically-add-header-to-every-response)

This filter is used to detect the chosen header on the request and put it on the response for any request coming through your server.

You can then check for this headers existence in the alert-error-component.ts and skip the error handling if it is present.