# 405 Not Allowed when using post method to Spring Rest API

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring, rest, http

I have created a simple Rest API and now I want to consume it with Ajax requests. I can use all CRUD operations with Postman. However when I try to make a post request I get "405 Not Allowed" and in the response header it says "Allow:GET, HEAD, OPTIONS". So I guess I have to tell spring to allow other servers to make POST, DELETE and PUT requests.

I can send hardcoded data in my js script to the server through ajax-post requests. It's when I try to send it through a html-form it doesn't work.

Could anyone help me with this please.

Comment: Provide us the POST, PUT and DELETE methods implemenation, please.

Comment: Which version of spring are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16190699/automatically-add-header-to-every-response), maybe you will have to supply this configuration in your filter to the requests:

```
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                        "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
```