# X-DownloadOptions , X-WebKit-CSP and Access-Control-Allow-Origin security headers in spring security

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I  have a spring based web application running on tomcat 7.0.77. 
I want to implement the security headers for spring web application using xml configuration.

How can I implement below security headers:
X-DownloadOptions, X-WebKit-CSP and Access-Control-Allow-Origin?

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: how to implement X-DownloadOptions , X-WebKit-CSP and Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers in tomcat application

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [automatically add header to every response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16190699/automatically-add-header-to-every-response)